# What is the meaning of "deserves a thorough airing"?

Tags: meaning

Which is correct? "deserves a thorough airing" or "deserves thorough airing"? Should "a" be there?

To put it into the content:
"This article deserves a thorough airing." To my understanding, it means we need to discuss or debate on this article. It does not indicate the article is wrong or correct. Am I correct? Or it indeed indicates something is wrong with this article?

Comment: It deserves to be brought out of (metaphorical) storage and looked at again. I've always heard it as '_an_ airing'.

Comment: The first dictionary I checked in, [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/airing), has << **airing** noun [S] (MAKING KNOWN)
 
an occasion when a subject is discussed in an open or public way:
_The arguments for and against the proposals have been given a good airing._ >>

Comment: I would say that using the article is more idiomatic.  But much depends on context and intent.